# Why is this integer range selection so slow?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently doing some inner joins in PostgreSQL, which I know aren't the speediest, but I've run into an efficiency issue.

The following query returns in 167ms

```
with structure as (
    SELECT s.id, s.terr_id, FROM structures s WHERE s.id=55
  )

SELECT r.id FROM territories t INNER JOIN structure ON (t.id = structure.terr_id)
LEFT JOIN resources r ON (
    t.rownum > r.rownum - 2
    AND t.rownum < r.rownum + 2
    AND t.colnum > r.colnum - 2
    AND t.colnum < r.colnum + 2
)
```

This query returns 9 rows. The columns are filled with primitives.

The table `territories` has 5 million rows. The table `resources` has 400,000 rows. The structure query is negligible.

I have indices set up on all of the rows involved. When I simply query as such:

```
with structure as (
    SELECT s.id, s.terr_id, FROM structures s WHERE s.id=55
  )

SELECT r.id FROM territories t INNER JOIN structure ON (t.id = structure.terr_id)
LEFT JOIN resources r ON (
    t.rownum > r.rownum - 2
    AND t.rownum < r.rownum + 2
    AND t.colnum = r.colnum
)
```

eliminating the `colnum` variation, the query returns 3 rows and only takes 11ms. If I were to run each row individually it would only take 33ms, a fraction of what it takes when combined. I've tried the `BETWEEN` keyword, using a box contains method, etc. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't get it, you're asking why PostgreSQL can't reduce complex and contrived join conditions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does that mean in this case? I have the same CTE in the second query.

Comment: First fix your query it doesn't run. Paste the query that generate the results exactly, then past the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE so we can see what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean when you say run "each row individually" to know that you have to work you're not including?

Comment: If that doesn't make sense if I say I want all the numbers between 3 and 5. It's work finding out what those numbers. It's not the same as saying where x = 3, and x = 4, and x = 5. Of course that extra work is going to come at a cost. You hope to make it back by not having to visit the table and index three times, but you're asking for too many assumptions without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: As Evan notes, nothing can be said with certainty without additional info. However, with the `colnum` no longer requiring a ranged lookup, it's possible that you've gone from a scan to an index seek in the query plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing stop using CTEs.

```
with structure as (
    SELECT s.id, s.terr_id
    FROM structures s
    WHERE s.id=55
)
SELECT r.id
FROM territories t
INNER JOIN structure ON (t.id = structure.terr_id)
LEFT JOIN resources r ON (
    t.rownum > r.rownum - 2
    AND t.rownum < r.rownum + 2
    AND t.colnum > r.colnum - 2
    AND t.colnum < r.colnum + 2
)
```

Get's rewritten as..

```
SELECT r.id
FROM structures AS s
JOIN territories t
  ON (t.id = s.terr_id)
LEFT JOIN resources r
  ON (
    t.rownum BETWEEN (r.rownum - 1) AND (r.rownum + 1)
    AND t.colnum BETWEEN (r.colnum - 1) AND (r.colnum + 1)
  )
WHERE s.id=55;
```

And equijoins are always going to be faster

1. They never fan and they're easy to optimize.
2. They're direct index lookups.

Comment: You need an `AS s` somewhere (I guess after `structures`). And your `BETWEEN` are off by 1, because you're having >, < and not >=, <=.

Comment: @joanolo good call on both of those! Fixed.

Comment: Does using the CTE actively hurt anything? I've been known to use a CTE instead of declaring variables in situations where I needed a single SQL statement (so, couldn't `DECLARE` variables, so all the hard-coded values would still be in one place, and be easy to update when/if needed.

Comment: @RDFozz https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

Comment: I'll test this out in my dataset as soon as I can. Sorry about the errant query, I cut out a lot of negligible information to make it more general.

Comment: Wow, what a difference. That reduced the query time to 67ms on my machine. I'll have to use this method on my other queries using CTEs as well and see if it improves performance.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - And, thanks for the article. Yes, a materialized CTE can certainly be an issue - potentially unnecessary reads/calculations, no access to the indexes on the original tables, etc. However, I'd assume the use I mentioned (a one row CTE consisting of hard-coded values, e.g. `WITH Vars (target_struct_id) AS (SELECT 55)`) would be little impacted by these issues. Will keep in mind the next time I'm messing w/ PostGreSQL!